# Trigger stage to run once one of the previous parallel steps successfully completed

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

As the title says, I'm trying to find whether it's possible to have a trigger at the beginning of a stage -- start running once **one** of the previous stage's parallel steps has finished.

Example:

Stages: 1)Prepare* - 2)Build* - 3.1)Small test set* || 3.2)Large test set - 4)Deploy*

The stages marked with * are compulsory. I don't need to wait for step 3.2 to complete in order to start running step 4.

So the question is, is there any way to trigger step 4 once step 3.1 is finished (regardless of whether step 3.2 is running)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming I've read this correctly...

Steps 3.1 and 3.2 are currently run in parallel, and then you want to start step 4 after 3.1 finishes but before 3.2 finishes?

My instinct is that you should have a parallel map with two entries.

Entry #1: Step 3.2 on it's own

Entry #2: Step 3.1 followed by Step 4

and that would be the end of your job, Step 4 would just live inside the parallel logic with Step 3.1.

Alternatively, you could setup another job to deploy and trigger that inside your parallel step after 3.1 finishes, but that seems overly complicated to me.

EDIT: Here's how the parallel map would look in code, assuming you're not using the declarative pipeline syntax

```
parallel (
  Entry1: { node {
    <Step 3.2 code>
 }},
  Entry2: { node {
    <Step 3.1 code>
    <Step 4 code>
 }}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. I wrote another separate job for Step 3.2. However, how would the Parallel Map with two entries work (in code)?

Comment: Edited that into the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I've used something similar to this, it was something like stages > stage > parallel  (but instead of <node> i used <step>)

Comment: Ah, yes, you're probably using the declarative syntax in that case. You don't have to have the nodes, feel free to drop that out.

Comment: The reason I dropped this idea though was the fact that I needed Step 4 to be a separate stage, but having 2 separate jobs works fine.

Comment: I am trying to have the step 4 shown as a separate stage itself in blue ocean. How is that possible? Is it possible if I use steps function?